# ASIHTTPRequest File Upload image

Tags: iphone, xcode, httpwebrequest, asihttprequest

I am trying write a simple image uploader using ASIHTTPRequest...

but at the code below....

```
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"iphone.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

I get below warning msg....

```
warning: 'ASIHTTPRequest' may not respond to '-setData:withFileName:andContentType:forKey:'
```

not too sure whats wrong since i got all the import added at top too

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Is your `request` an instance of `ASIHTTPRequest`?

Or is `request` an instance of `ASIFormDataRequest`?

To use the method `-setData:withFileName:andContentType:forKey:` your `request` must be an instance of `ASIFormDataRequest`.

If `request` is an instance of `ASIHTTPRequest`, the above method is definitely unavailable.

Secondly, if you look at the code in `ASIFormDataRequest.h`, you'll notice that `ASIFormDataRequest` is a subclass of `ASIHTTPRequest`:

```
@interface ASIFormDataRequest : ASIHTTPRequest
```

Therefore, it would be unnecessary to import `ASIHTTPRequest.h` if you just import `ASIFormDataRequest.h` and then instantiate `request` as an instance of `ASIFormDataRequest`.

An instance of `ASIFormDataRequest` will have all the same methods and properties of an instance of `ASIHTTPRequest`, with all the extra functionality of an `ASIFormDataRequest` request.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the mistable my request was really wrong!! should of used ASIFormDataRequest and not ASIHTTPRequest!!